# Binary quantization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I would like to binary quantize vector in order to use it in loss function.
However I am not sure this is the right way.

```
def _binary_quantize1(h):
    with tf.name_scope('binary_quantization'):
        return tf.cast(h > tf.constant(0.5, shape=tf.shape(h)), tf.float32)

def _binary_quantize2(h):
    with tf.name_scope('binary_quantization'):
        return tf.sign(tf.round(h), name='quantized')
```

How would you approach such functionality? Will the gradient pass ok through such function?

EDIT:

I want to do something like this function in tensorflow https://github.com/kevinlin311tw/cvpr16-deepbit/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/K2_min_quantize_loss_layer.cpp

Comment: To specify more I am repimplementing this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08798v1.pdf and having trouble implementing binary quantization.

Comment: I am curious, how would you minimize a loss based on a discretization? I don't expect tf's gradient descent tools to work.

Comment: There is repository doing something similar upon which the other paper is build : https://github.com/kevinlin311tw/cvpr16-deepbit

Comment: If I understand correctly they do not use the binarization in the loss, but the "soft" output before thresholding.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to implement it but my current version looks like this: https://gist.github.com/kovacspeter/1ba40ff3de3597e6f939018c48fa3f3d